# nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, ubuntu-16.04, udp

I have the latest NGINX from ppa installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

> nginx version: nginx/1.12.1

From my understanding, it should support stream and UDP load balancing.

But I get this error message:

```
nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf:3
```

This is my config in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf`

```
stream {
        upstream backend {
                least_conn;
                server 172.31.9.51 fail_timeout=10s;
                server 172.31.20.140 fail_timeout=10s;
        }

        server {
                listen          500 udp;
                listen          4500 udp;
                proxy_pass      backend;
                proxy_timeout   1s;
                proxy_responses 1;
                error_log       logs/dns.log;
        }
}
```

Comment: is that the whole file?

Comment: Yes Mike. This is the whole file.

Comment: The `nginx` configuration file is located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. The `stream` block is a top-level block. Ensure that files located in the `conf.d` directory are included into the top-level.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

stream needs to be on the same level as http block so like

```
http { foo }
stream { bar }
```

My guess is your include for `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` is located in the `http {}` block and not outside of it. Checkout the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf for the include and maybe you have to make a new one for the stream section

Comment: I've updated the question with the path of my config. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf`. You are right! The include is inside the http.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I have a follow-up issue that I don't understand. Why do I need to specify the port for upstream? `nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "172.31.9.51"`. Since the UDP ports are defined already under server...

Comment: you need to tell it what ports to send back to like `server 172.31.9.51:4500 fail_timeout=10s;`

Comment: Interestingly, the default `nginx` Docker image does exactly this: "My guess is your include for /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf is located in the http {} block and not outside of it.".  So in that Docker image, you cannot use `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` to add `stream` directives.

Comment: " maybe you have to make a new one for the stream section" what would that look like? currently I have the default /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  that already had the include statement for /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf include statement.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error with a default `nginx` Docker image, I tried to solve it with a small change to the DockerFile:

```ruby
COPY docker/ngnix/ngnix.conf /tmp/docker.nginx
COPY docker/ngnix/stream.conf /etc/nginx/stream.conf
RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT','$DOMAIN' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN echo 'include /etc/nginx/stream.conf;' >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

stream.conf

```
stream{
  server{ 
    ...  
  }
}
```

I am about to find out if this version of `nginx` was built with the stream module...

P.S. **It deployed with no errors**

+1
I am connected from my terminal into Postgres on Kubernetes on AWS through the LoadBalancer and the reverse proxy! Now, SSL...

Comment: I utilized the idea of 
```COPY docker/ngnix/stream.conf /etc/nginx/stream.conf```